# What explains minute time frame stocks gaps?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, chart

Gaps (the difference between the close and open prices of two consecutive periods) between two days can be understood by the many events that may happen between the market closing and the market opening.
However, what can explain gaps in a one-minute time frame of an intraday chart?

[image: Example of a candle intraday chart with gaps]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eZ8b.png)

Comment: Say Carlos, good question, what is the appox volume ***in each minute*** ?  (I don't understand the graph scales.)  It seems incredibly unlikely that in the split second from one-minute to another there would *always* be a price difference.  I can only see one pair of candles where it asserts they match.

Comment: Carlos - those don't seem to be showing minutes **at all** .. ???  there is nothing like sixty, per one hour indicating on the bottom axis ??????

Comment: @Fattie - As I mentioned in my reply to you below my answer, the  OP edited the question and he changed the chart.  The original chart had one minute bars and the current chart has five minute bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side of your chart depicts trading during regular hours on 12/02.  There's a candle every minute because the security is being traded actively.

The left side of the chart depicts trading during the after market on 12/01 and the pre-market on 12/02.  Liquidity is low during after extended hours trading and if a trade doesn't occur during a one minute time frame, there is no candle.

Comment: Right, that may be misleading the question focus, which is: take two consecutive minutes (in the same day) Why the open price is different from the close price of the previous minute. I will try to change the chart. Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that the collation  of the past minute's O,H,L,C data points ends at 00:01:00 and that the next one minute collection of O,H,L,C begins at 00:01:01.  Therefore the first trade of the second minute (the open) may be the same or different than the close of the previous minute.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @BobBaerker , regarding only the answer here (not the comment below which answers the question).  Wait - isn't liquidity shown by the little thingies down the bottom of that image?  Liquidity seems to be the same throughout that whole chart, no?

Comment: @Fattie - You are correct, to a point.  The problem is that the OP has edited the question and he changed the chart.  You'll have to view the editing to see the original chart.

Comment: ah, thanks for the explain, @BobBaerker

Comment: @BobBaerker I got a small confirmation:
                                            O             H             L              C          N
2020-12-01 13:27 123.76 123.78 123.73 123.73 0
2020-12-01 13:26 123.73 123.76 123.7 123.76 1

N in the number of operations, which is 0 at 13:37. Under that condition, O at that time is equal to C at 13:36. This one of the 57 cases a found in my data. Thanks again.